# Do instance methods in python need a self parameter

Tags: python, class, methods

I'm building a simple platformer game and I'm using a `collided_left` method from my `Coords` class in my `Sprite` class. I have a attribute in the `Sprite` class which creates an object in the `Coords` class but the `collided_left` method doesn't have a self parameter so when I try to call it in my `Sprite` class, I get a `name 'collided_left' is not defined` error.
Is there anything I can do to call the method without adding a self attribute?

Comment: Why not just add the `self` parameter?

Comment: This is covered in any tutorial on classes and methods.  By design and definition, and instance method begins with an instance parameter.

Comment: Could you also show us some code snippets so we able to understand you better?

Answer (score 1):

> Do instance methods in python need a self parameter

Yes. There are three types of a method, that are instance method, class method, and static method. An instance method is a method that is intended to make some change to an instance or to call another instance method.  Therefore, instance method MUST have a self parameter.

> Is there anything I can do to call the method without adding a self attribute?

You can change the method into a static method. A static method is a method that's not intended to make any change to any instance class nor call other instance methods. Therefore, you don't have to pass the self parameter.

If you want to declare a static method, you just need to wrap it with the built-in `staticmethod`. Here's the example:

```
>>> class ThisIsClass():
    @staticmethod
    def your_method_name(a, b):
        return a + b

    
>>> instance = ThisIsClass()
>>> instance.your_method_name(1, 2)
3
```